# How to generate dynamic components in table from single child component?

Tags: vue.js

I have parent component which contains table and has a 'plus' button which opens child component to show bootstrap popover.
Currently this popover is created for all plus buttons in the table on load from parent component. I would like to create each popover only on click of the plus button .

table view with button below.
[image]

parentComponent.vue
`

```
<template>
   <div v-if="item">
      <icon
        :id="`item-popover-${ index }`"
        icon="plus-circle"
      />
   </div>
   <component
     :is="reserveView"
     :id="`item-popover-${ index }`"
    />
</template>
<script>
import ReservePopover from './reserve-popover'

export default {
    data () {
      return {
        reserveView: 'reserve-popover'
      }
    }
}
</script>
```

` .

**Issue:**
- As soon as table loads all the child components are created as well.
- plus button is hidden in instances slots are not available. After clicking on the red trash button plus button reappears but the child component popover is not created unless page is refreshed.
[image]

**Desired:**
the component popover is created only on click of the plus icon and not before that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Is the issue that you are currently creating one pop-over for each button but want to change that to create one total pop-over that dynamically loads relevant content when a button is clicked?

Comment: @retrograde yes that is the issue. Currently popover is created for each button which results in quite a few popovers created on load. I'm looking for a way to not create any popovers on initial load....popover is only created once button is clicked with relevant content. Any suggestions would be helpful